# How to deal with `*` expansion when there are no files

Tags: bash

I am making a shell script that allows you to select a file from a directory using YAD. I am doing this:

```
  list='';
  exc='!'
  for f in "$SHOTS_NOT_CONVERTED_DIR"/*;do
    f=`basename $f`
    list="${list}${exc}${f}"
  done
```

The problem is that if there are no files in that directory, I end up with a selection with `*`.

What's the easiest, most elegant way to make this work in Bash?
The goal is to have an *empty* list if there are no files there.

Comment: Inside the loop before you call basename: `[[ -f $f ]] || break`.  Make sure you use `[[` not `[` (otherwise the * will attempt to expand again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` expansion is called a *glob expressions*. The bash manual calls it [*filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

You need to set the `nullglob` option. Doing so gives you an empty result if the glob expression does not find files:

```
shopt -s nullglob

list='';
exc='!'
for f in "$SHOTS_NOT_CONVERTED_DIR"/*;do
    # Btw, use $() instead of ``
    f=$(basename "$f")
    list="${list}${exc}${f}"
done
```